Double Integral with product of sign functions involved
I'm trying to calculate this integral for arbitary $k$:
$$I_k = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \{ (x^d + y^d) \prod_{i=1}^{k} sgn(x-p_i) sgn(y-p_i) \} dx dy$$
Under the following conditions:

$0 < p_i < 1$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$
$p_i < p_{i+1}$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k-1$

computing the integral for a few terms and after some tedious calculations, we get:
$$I_4 = \frac{2}{1 + d}\left(1 + 2(p_1 - p_2 + p_3 - p_4 )\right)\left(1 + 2(p_1^{d+1} - p_2^{d+1} + p_3^{d+1} - p_4^{d+1})\right)$$
$$I_5 = \frac{2}{1 + d}\left(-1 + 2(p_1 - p_2 + p_3 - p_4 + p_5)\right)\left(-1 + 2(p_1^{d+1} - p_2^{d+1} + p_3^{d+1} - p_4^{d+1} + p_5^{d+1})\right)$$
So, It seems like the following formula should be true:
$$I_k = \frac{2}{1 + d}\left((-1)^k + 2\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+1}p_i\right)\left((-1)^k + 2\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+1}p_i^{d+1}\right)$$
However, I can't find a way to show this rigorously. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Is $d$ and arbitrary natural number?

My mistake for not providing $d$. $d \in (0, +\infty)$ @Hume2

At first, you can break it into two integrals:$$
I_k = \int_0^1\int_0^1x^d\prod_{i=0}^{k}\mathrm{sgn}(x-p_i)\mathrm{sgn}(y-p_i)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy + \int_0^1\int_0^1y^d\prod_{i=0}^{k}\mathrm{sgn}(x-p_i)\mathrm{sgn}(y-p_i)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
$$
Then you can notice that both parts are the same integral, except that the symbols $x$ and $y$ are swapped. We can therefore rewrite it as:$$
I_k = 2\int_0^1\int_0^1x^d\prod_{i=0}^{k}\mathrm{sgn}(x-p_i)\mathrm{sgn}(y-p_i)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
Using Fubini's Theorem, we get:$$
I_k = 2\int_0^1x^d\prod_{i=0}^{k}\mathrm{sgn}(x-p_i)\mathrm dx\int_0^1\mathrm{sgn}(y-p_i)\mathrm dy$$
Now we can get rid of the signum functions. For convenience, let's put $p_0=0$ and $p_{k+1}=1$:$$
I_k = 2\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\int_{p_i}^{p_{i+1}}x^d(-1)^{k-i}\mathrm dx\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\int_{p_i}^{p_{i+1}}(-1)^{k-i}\mathrm dy\right)
$$
These integrals can be now solved:$$
I_k = 2\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\left[\frac{x^{d+1}}{d+1}(-1)^{k-i}\right]_{p_i}^{p_{i+1}}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\left[y(-1)^{k-i}\right]_{p_i}^{p_{i+1}}\right)
$$
From this, you get:$$
I_k=\frac{2}{d+1}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-i}p_i^{d+1}\right)\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-i}p_i\right)
$$
And that is basically what you got.

Thank you very much. I only had one question regarding your solution, can we consider $p_0 = 0$ and $p_{k+1} = 1$? (Because $0<p_i<1$) @hume2

You don't define $p_0$ and $p_{k+1}$ at all, therefore you didn't give any constraint at them. I used these extra symbols to make the formula easier to comprehend. Otherwise, I would have to rewrite these sums into three parts: first part would be an integral from 0 to $p_1$, the second part would be the sum of all integral in between, and the third part would be an integral from $p_k$ to 1. So using symbols $p_0$ for 0 and $p_{k+1}$ for 1 makes the formula easier to read.

That makes sense, thanks!
